# Can't use Python multiprocessing with large amount of calculations

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I have to speed up my current code to do around 10^6 operations in a feasible time. Before I used multiprocessing in my the actual document I tried to do it in a mock case. Following is my attempt:

```
def chunkIt(seq, num):
    avg = len(seq) / float(num)
    out = []
    last = 0.0

    while last < len(seq):
        out.append(seq[int(last):int(last + avg)])
        last += avg

    return out
 
def do_something(List):
    # in real case this function takes about 0.5 seconds to finish for each 
    iteration
    turn = []
    for e in List:
        turn.append((e[0]**2, e[1]**2,e[2]**2))
    return turn
    
t1 = time.time()

List = []
#in the real case these 20's can go as high as 150
for i in range(1,20-2):
    for k in range(i+1,20-1):
        for j in range(k+1,20):
            List.append((i,k,j))
            
t3 = time.time() 
test = []    

List = chunkIt(List,3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(do_something,List)
        for result in results:
            test.append(result)       
    
test= np.array(test)
t2 = time.time()

T = t2-t1
T2 = t3-t1
```

However, when I increase the size of my "List" my computer tires to use all of my RAM and CPU and freezes. I even cut my "List" into 3 pieces so it will only use 3 of my cores. However, nothing changed. Also, when I tried to use it on a smaller data set I noticed the code ran much slower than when it ran on a single core.
I am still very new to multiprocessing in Python, am I doing something wrong. I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: Every subprocess will be creating the main `List` variable and then chunking it - which is probably not helping. Put all that setup code inside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block

Comment: And dont use the variable name List it's a reserved name in Python

Comment: `when I increase the size of my "List" my computer tires to use all of my RAM and CPU and freezes`. How big are you making your 'list'? Using 150x150x150 gives a list of about 3M items, and that pickles to about 40MB. I wonder if you are using a much larger data set?

Comment: you could use `(x**2 for x in e)` instead of `(e[0]**2, e[1]**2,e[2]**2)` and then you can send longer tuples.

Comment: @furas `(x**2 for x in e)` is not a `tuple`; it's a generator expression.  You need `tuple(x**2 for x in e)`.

Comment: @Booboo it is detail which was not important in my idea - importa was to use loop to work with longer data.

Comment: I had the same problem, I had large arrays though, I used imap it significantly increased the run time but still I ended up with all my memory being used up.

Comment: @JawadAhmadKhan Is there a possibility you did not do it correctly. The argument to `imap` needs to be a generator or generator expression.

Comment: @Booboo Hi, yes it may have been, I was web scraping a lot of data and appending it to the lists, I have 16GB of ram in my system using map my memory was being fulled and after some processing time I was getting broken pipe error, then I used the imap an was clearing my lists as each listing data was extracted, imap returned data at each execution of cycle, it pretty much increased my execution time but still I got the same error for bigger run time.

Comment: @Booboo Here is the question I asked a while ago, I will really appreciate if you could help me understand it better, please check out the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63049966/brokenpipeerror-errno-32-python-multiprocessing

Comment: @JawadAhmadKhan I think I will have a chance later on today to take a look at it.

Comment: @furas I am indeed making it as big as 150x150x150 and at that point, my computer just freezes.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce memory usage, I suggest you use instead the `multiprocessing` module and specifically the [imap method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=imap_unordered#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap) method (or [imap_unordered](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=imap_unordered#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap_unordered) method). Unlike the `map` method of either `multiprocessing.Pool` or `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`, the *iterable* argument is processed *lazily*. What this means is that if you use a generator function or generator expression for the *iterable* argument, you do not need to create the complete list of arguments in memory; as a processor in the pool become free and ready to execute more tasks, the generator will be called upon to generate the next argument for the `imap` call.

By default a *chunksize* value of 1 is used, which can be inefficient for a large *iterable* size. When using `map` and the default value of `None` for the *chunksize* argument, the pool will look at the length of the *iterable* first converting it to a `list` if necessary and then compute what it deems to be an efficient *chunksize* based on that length and the size of the pool. When using `imap` or `imap_unordered`, converting the *iterable* to a `list` would defeat the whole purpose of using that method. But if you know what that size would be (more or less) if the *iterable* were converted to a list, then there is no reason not to apply the same *chunksize* calculation the `map` method would have, and that is what is done below.

The following benchmarks perform the same processing first as a single process and then using multiprocessing using `imap` where each invocation of `do_something` on my desktop takes approximately .5 seconds. `do_something` now has been modified to just process a *single* i, k, j tuple as there is no longer any need to break up anything into smaller lists:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import time

def half_second():
    HALF_SECOND_ITERATIONS = 10_000_000
    sum = 0
    for _ in range(HALF_SECOND_ITERATIONS):
        sum += 1
    return sum

def do_something(tpl):
    # in real case this function takes about 0.5 seconds to finish for each  iteration
    half_second() # on my desktop
    return tpl[0]**2, tpl[1]**2, tpl[2]**2

"""
def generate_tpls():
    for i in range(1, 20-2):
        for k in range(i+1, 20-1):
            for j in range(k+1, 20):
                yield i, k, j
"""

# Use smaller number of tuples so we finish in a reasonable amount of time:
def generate_tpls():
    # 64 tuples:
    for i in range(1, 5):
        for k in range(1, 5):
            for j in range(1, 5):
                yield i, k, j

def benchmark1():
    """ single processing """
    t = time.time()
    for tpl in generate_tpls():
        result = do_something(tpl)
    print('benchmark1 time:', time.time() - t)

def compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size):
    """ This is more-or-less the function used by the Pool.map method """
    chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize

def benchmark2():
    """ multiprocssing """
    t = time.time()
    pool_size = cpu_count() # 8 logical cores (4 physical cores)
    N_TUPLES = 64 # number of tuples that will be generated
    pool = Pool(pool_size)
    chunksize = compute_chunksize(N_TUPLES, pool_size)
    for result in pool.imap(do_something, generate_tpls(), chunksize=chunksize):
        pass
    print('benchmark2 time:', time.time() - t)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    benchmark1()
    benchmark2()
```

Prints:

```
benchmark1 time: 32.261038303375244
benchmark2 time: 8.174998044967651
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, when I increase the number of tuples to around 100 ish, the same problem is still there. PC just chokes and freezes. While benchmark1 can at least finish running the code.

Comment: First, I updated the code to add variable N_TUPLES in `benchmark2` to emphasize that the calculation of `chunksize` depends on the number of tuples that you will ultimately be generating. Second, I think you will need to update your question with your actual `do_something(tpl)` function definition so we can see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

The nested For loops creating the array before the main definition appears to be the problem. Moving that part to underneath the main definition clears up any memory problems.

```
def chunkIt(seq, num):
    avg = len(seq) / float(num)
    out = []
    last = 0.0

    while last < len(seq):
        out.append(seq[int(last):int(last + avg)])
        last += avg

    return out
 
def do_something(List):
    # in real case this function takes about 0.5 seconds to finish for each 
    iteration
    turn = []
    for e in List:
        turn.append((e[0]**2, e[1]**2,e[2]**2))
    return turn
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
   t1 = time.time()

   List = []
   #in the real case these 20's can go as high as 150
   for i in range(1,20-2):
     for k in range(i+1,20-1):
        for j in range(k+1,20):
            List.append((i,k,j))
            
   t3 = time.time() 
   test = []    

   List = chunkIt(List,3)
   with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(do_something,List)
        for result in results:
            test.append(result)       
    
   test= np.array(test)
   t2 = time.time()

   T = t2-t1
   T2 = t3-t1
```